# Using fancybox to open a pop up HTML page

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm just getting to grips with Fancybox, and have made it work ok opening a larger image from a thumbnail.

Now what I'd like to do, is open a pop up window page (HTML page) from a link within the parent window, so that the popup (child window) get the focus, and the parent page behind greys out until the child is closed again.

It's probably dead simple, like me...hope someone can help?

Cheers.

Comment: Do you really mean "popup"? Half the point of Fancybox is to avoid using popups and display content in overlays instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, Fancybox's website has an example: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples

Check out the iframe example. Basically set the href of your `<a>` tag to the page you want, and in the Fancybox JS, set `type: 'iframe'` (not necessarily required, but if Fancybox fails to correctly identify the type, you can set it manually this way).

Another example: http://jsfiddle.net/VWsRP/1/